# MVP within Winforms Form application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wpf, winforms, mvvm

I have read this good [article](http://joel.inpointform.net/software-development/mvvm-vs-mvp-vs-mvc-the-differences-explained/) and I need to know the meaning of this statement:

**MVP**

> Use in situations where binding via a datacontext is not possible.
> Windows Forms is a perfect example of this.  In order to separate the
> view from the model, a presenter is needed.  Since the view cannot
> directly bind to the presenter, information must be passed to it view
> an interface (IView).

I mean is it true that binding in WinForms isn't possible?

Besides, is it true that MVP is suitable for WinForms ONLY because:

1. it separates the logic layer from the view
2. The  use of MVVM or MVC is not recommended

Is there another reason ?

Comment: the level of support for DataBinding (as pretty much anything else) in winforms is very limited. Therefore it doesn't really make sense to try to force winforms to MVVM because you need to spend a lot of time and effort implementing workarounds to winforms' limitations. winforms is a really old technology not recommended for any new projects, only to maintain legacy applications. No one really cares about trying to do MVVM on winforms because current, XAML-based technologies support MVVM much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to retrofit any pattern to WinForms but it was observed in time that MVP works best with WinForms.